# Spring Rest - passing an Object which contains list of objects to post request

Tags: spring

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
headers.add("Authorization", "1234");
List<AdhocRequestParameters> list = new ArrayList<>();
AdhocRequestParameters AdhocRequestParameters = new AdhocRequestParameters("partitionCode","GG",AdhocRequestParameterType.STRING);

list.add(AdhocRequestParameters);

AdhocParameters params = new AdhocParameters("3301",list);
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(params,headers);

//ResponseEntity<String> httpResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(hURL,entity, String.class);
//ResponseEntity<String> httpResponse = restTemplate.exchange(hURL,HttpMethod.POST,entity, String.class);

ResponseEntity<String> httpResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(hURL,entity, String.class);
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/invokeAdhocJob/", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json","application/xml"})
public ResponseEntity<String> submitAdhocJob(@RequestHeader(value="Accept") String acceptMediaType,@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String userId,
                                            @RequestBody AdhocParameters adhocParameters)
{
    System.out.println(adhocParameters.getJobId());
    System.out.println(adhocParameters.getList());
    System.out.println(userId);
    System.out.println(acceptMediaType);

      return new ResponseEntity<>(jobInvoked,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? As is this question is just a code dump and quite unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.